# Get only the first of multiple occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
(\w+)(?=.*\1)
```

This successfully matches the multiple occurrence of words. There is a problem, though. Consider this case:

```
dog cat dog cat cat
```

The regex matches `cat` twice, since there are two occurrences of `cat` that are followed by `cat`. But I only want one match for every word that occurs multiple times.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is it necessary to be done in regex? You can easily get unique values out of resulting array.

Comment: i'm aware i could easily solve this in other ways, but i'd like to know how it could be done with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done by *regex*.

Instead of matching use `replace`.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qT5pO4/2

Comment: Consider what happens when there's a word that's [not repeated](https://regex101.com/r/qT5pO4/1) (without `\b` it just fails to match the _word_).

Comment: But the problem is still there: word `den` should not be there, it's not repeated. And after the replacement there's no way to filter it out.

Comment: @raina77ow that problem can be easily solved by runnin a `replace` first for words not having multiple occurances

Comment: Yes, I agree: first filter out the non-repeated words, then filter out all the repetitions but their last appearances. I think I'd prefer the dictionary approach (when the words are filtered out after they're collected), but the code you've shown is certainly a useful technique. +1, overall. )

Comment: @raina77ow yeah dictionary would be right approach.But i got no idea about it :P